# Not able to send email to gmail address in PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am trying to send an email from PHP.

The below code works fine when the **From** address is a **Non-Gmail address**.

However, when I use a **Gmail address** as a **From** Address, I don't receive the email. I have checked spam as well.

Can you tell any reason for this behaviour?

```php
<?php 
    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['emailto']) ||
        !isset($_REQUEST['emailsub']) ||
        !isset($_REQUEST['emailfrom']) ||
        !isset($_REQUEST['emailsub'])) {
            exit;
    }

    $emailto = $_REQUEST['emailto'] ;
    $emailsub = $_REQUEST['emailsub'] ;
    $emailfrom = $_REQUEST['emailfrom'] ;
    $emailmsg = $_REQUEST['emailmsg'] ;
 
    // create email headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $emailfrom . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $emailfrom . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    
    mail($emailto, $emailsub, $emailmsg, $headers));

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use PhpMailer or SwiftMailer for sending mails over SMTP with Gmail account. Sending mails from custom/local mail server often is banned as a SPAM or sent to grey lists filters. Quite possible that these mails will arive after few hours... or not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use some GMAIL.COM email address as FROM address, you must use GMAIL.COM SMTP server to send out emails. Your best shot is to use phpMailer as @biesior already mentioned.